# Как сделать такое в консоле

Tags: c#, консоль

Скажите, как реализовать такую вещь в консоли: вот есть в командной строке проверка диска, там одна строка потом двоеточие, и постоянно разные имена файлов пишутся имена файлов, но сама строка не меняется. А когда я так же хочу сделать, то у меня постоянно строки вниз уходят, и получается для каждого файла новая строка. Как сделать так, чтобы всё было на одной строке только, имена менялись?

Comment: Ну если не искать библиотеку, то выводить символ `\r` и повторять вывод строки. Только не забыть делать flush (обычно в консоли буферизация на строку)

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, вы что-то такое хотели:

```
    var d = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Games\Battlefield 3\Data\");

    foreach (var s in d)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
```

P.S. Автор, не обижайтесь, но прежде чем программировать, учите русский язык - пишете как неграмотная школота

Comment: @DreamChild Однако Вы -- жестокое дитя. Console.Clear()... Чтобы не подсматривали, что на экране раньше было?

Comment: может, я чего-то не понял из несвязной речи автора, но он же вроде бы хочет, чтобы все это великолепие выводилось на одной строке. Я даже процитирую бессмертные слова автора: "у меня постоянно строки вниз уходят, и получается для каждого файла новая строка, а как сделать так чтобы всё было на одной строке только имена менялись?" Или я ошибаюсь?))

Comment: "Нет, всё правильно, всё это правильно" (c) т. Саахов. Да, имена файлов выводятся в одной строке, но. Это единственная строка на экране. Все остальные Clear() почикал. Вам самому такое бы понравилось? У ТС получается, что он выводит в последней строке, переводит строчку и экран скроллингом смещается вверх. А если так?

        var p = 1;
        foreach (var s in d)
        {
            Console.Write("".PadRight(p));
            Console.Write('\r');
            Console.Write(s);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            Console.Write('\r');
            p = s.Length;
        }

Comment: я просто не стал с этим заморачиваться, посчитав, что у автора это, скорее всего, учебное задание из разряда "Hello World" (хотя, может, и ошибаюсь). Но ваш ответ, безусловно, лучше